# Which class has the implementation of CrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, netbeans, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA to create and query my tables.

This is my `UserService` class,

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public User saveUser(User u) {
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(u); //<----- line that I debug
        return savedUser;
    }
    
    public boolean usernameExists(String username) {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByUsername(username); //<----- line that I debug
        return !users.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

and this is the `UserRepository` class

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    public List<User> findByUsername(String username);    
}
```

I am debugging my code and when the reach the above '*linesToDebug*', I do a Step-Into in my IDE, hoping I would be taken to the implementation of the methods `save()` and `findByUsername()`, but nothing happens, the user is saved to the repository and my IDE (**Netbeans 8.0**) does not navigate to the implementation of these methods.

Which class has these methods implemented?

Edit:
This is what I get in the console on the save() method:

```
2021-06-06 16:24:36.779 DEBUG 6948 --- [nio-8181-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into user (date_created, password, username) values (?, ?, ?)
2021-06-06 16:24:36.784 TRACE 6948 --- [nio-8181-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Sun Jun 06 16:24:27 IST 2021]
2021-06-06 16:24:36.791 TRACE 6948 --- [nio-8181-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [$2a$10$Ad0G05HssJUb4xaEMTqFTOlWZijMbXBSLSgyxbjVQzOEdZn7Lxuz2]
```

But there is no class named `SQL` in `org.hibernate` package .

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: HI, I am using Netbeans 8.0

Comment: Are you able to view the source code for `CrudRepository` ?

Comment: Yes, I have the sources attached so I can navigate to the source code for CrudRepository

Comment: In some IDEs there is a setting to enable/disable debugging into .class files/ libraries. Maybe in your case it might be disabled.

Comment: Maybe these could help https://stackoverflow.com/q/87411/7804477 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610576/7804477

Comment: HI, I've never seen a debugger go into .class files when there's no source code. I may be completely wrong here. My IDE has no custom setting to disable such debugging.

Comment: You said you had attached the source right?

Comment: Yes, I have the sources attached. To be precise, I have the sources for spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar attached

Comment: Then what did you mean by "***I've never seen a debugger go into .class files when there's no source code***"

Comment: I mean the debugger control going to a .class file (inside some jar) when the sources of the jar file are not attached. I have never seen such a case.

Comment: spring creates an implementation for the UserRepository interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your actual problem this question and its answers might help:
[How do I step into an implemented method in debug mode in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728959/how-do-i-step-into-an-implemented-method-in-debug-mode-in-netbeans)

Regarding the question you asked in the title:

The `CrudRepository` implementation in Spring Data JPA is [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java)

Regarding the question in the body of your post:
`public List<User> findByUsername(String username);`
is not part of an preexisting interface. So there is no direct implementation for it. Instead some dynamic code gets executed via proxies.

A good entry point to debug this is [`PartTreeJpaQuery.getExecution()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java#L124) if you are interested in the construction of the query and [`AbstractJpaQuery.execute()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/AbstractJpaQuery.java#L142) if you are more interested in the actual execution of the query.

Comment: Hi, I just saw the source code for SimpleJPARepository. It provides an implementation for 2 interfaces JpaRepositoryImplementation and  JpaRepository. It does not implement the CrudRepository interface

Comment: It does. `JpaRepository` extends `CrudRepository`